# Python, openpyxl. How to form a dictionary not from columns but from rows

Tags: python, openpyxl

How to make a dictionary where the keys are values from the cells of the first column and the values to these keys are data from other columns?

| Title | Price | Link | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ball | 100 | Link | text |
| Tshort | 200 | Link2 | text2 |

Need:

[{'title': 'Ball','Price': 100, 'Link': Link, 'Description': text}, {'title': 'Tshort','Price': 200, 'Link': Link2, 'Description': text2}]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('itemtablex.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

allitemdict = { col[0]: col[1:] for col in zip(*ws.values) } # this work, but that's not what I need
```

I can't figure out how to form a dictionary not from columns but from rows

Comment: Use the positions of the keys from the first row for the other rows. This will let you repeatedly zip over the keys and values to create your dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('itemtablex.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl')
allitemdicts = df.to_dict('records')
```

**With openpyxl.worksheet** presenting it as records is a bit more complicated, because a worksheet is just unstructured collection of cells. But you always can iterate over your rows, for example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('itemtablex.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

allitemdicts = []
headers = [header.value for header in ws[1]]
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    allitemdicts.append({header: row[idx] for idx, header in enumerate(headers)})
```